# gradio blocks as outputs in gr.Interface

Tags: gradio

I wish to plot k images (upto 9) in a 3x3 grid. I have figured out how to plot in the 3x3 grid using `gr.Blocks`, however I do not know how to make this part of a gradio interface. How do I fix the following:

```py
def get_sampled_images(k: int):
    sample_images = [Image.fromarray(np.random.randint(0, 255, (100, 100)).astype('uint8')) for _ in range(k)]
    sample_titles = [f"Image {i+1}" for i in range(k)]

    return sample_images, sample_titles

def plot_images(k: int):
    sample_images, sample_titles = get_sampled_images(int(k))
    batch_size = 3
    with gr.Blocks() as blocks:
        for i in range(0, len(sample_images), batch_size):
            with gr.Row():
                j = i
                while j < len(sample_images) and j < i + batch_size:
                    image = gr.Image(sample_images[j], label=sample_titles[j])
                    j += 1
                    
    return blocks
            
demo = gr.Interface(fn=plot_images, inputs="text", outputs=gr.Blocks)
demo.launch()
```

Note that the following does work,

```py
demo = plot_images(8)
demo.launch()
```